# Uncaught ReferenceError: doFeedBack is not defined

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am converting a vbscript code to javascript. The page is working fine however, on loading the page, a vbscript function is supposed to execute but it is not responding to my conversion. Its purpose is just to inform the user that the value has been submitted or alert error. the function is assigned to body attribute onload.

I have converted the code to javascript.

```
<script>
    function doFeedback(){
        Msg = "<%=MoveMsg%>"
        SKU = "<%=strSKU%>"
        PageID = "<%=PageID%>"
        falseSubmit = "<%=falseSubmit%>" 

        if(Msg!=""){

            Msg2 =  "Stock Move Status for SKU : " + SKU +"\r\n\r\n"
            test = Msg.split("#")
            UB = test.length 
            UB = UB -1
            for( i = 0; i<=UB; i++){
          Msg2 = Msg2 + test(i) +"\r\n"
       }
       if (Msg.substring(0,3)=="ERR"){
          Msg2 = Msg2 +"\r\n"+"Review stock values at current locations 
               and repeat move(s)."

       }

       confirm(Msg2)    


        }

        //Preselect Menu Option
        setMenuOption("1")
   }

</script>
```

Here is the old VBScript procedure that is now commented out.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
   Sub doFeedBack()

      Msg = "<%=MoveMsg%>"
      SKU = "<%=strSKU%>"
      PageID = "<%=PageID%>"
      falseSubmit = "<%=falseSubmit%>"

      if Msg <> "" then

          Msg2 = "Stock Move Status for SKU : " & SKU & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
          test = split(Msg,"#")
          UB = Ubound(test)
          for i = 0 to UB
              Msg2 = Msg2 & test(i) & vbcrlf
          next

          If Mid(Msg,1,3) = "ERR" then
               msg2 = msg2 & vbcrlf & "Review stock values at current 
               locations and repeat move(s)."
          end if

          MsgBox(Msg2)

          ' ------- added SH 06/03/2012 '
          ' Reload page using a "get stock at location" request to avoid user 
          refreshing page and submitting same stock move twice by mistake '
          getStockDetail(SKU)

     end if

      ' Preselect Menu Option
       setMenuOption("1")

 End Sub


</script>
```

Comment: Need some more information here.

Comment: Can you have both the VBScript procedure and the JavaScript function named the same? How will it know which to run? The question doesn't make a huge amount of sense to be honest, as @ChasenBettinger says we need more information.

Comment: the vbscript code is not browser compatible  that is why I am converting all the functions in the file from vbscript to javascript. all other functions have been converted and they are perfectly ok except this one. They are the same name because my intention is to remove the vbscript function and replace it javascript function. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you have to downvote my response and even flag it. I explained to you my challenge the very best way I can. I showed what the problem is and what I have done. I found solution to my problem and I shared it. If my assumption is right, this platform is for everyone, those new to programming and those that have been  for years. Please be kind and gentle. You don't  have to scare people off just because they are not in your league. Thanks

Comment: @OlayinkaPopoola can only assume the down-votes are because of the lack of clarity. We don't need to know why you are doing it but how. You mention *"the function is assigned to body attribute onload"* but VBScript isn't case sensitive, how is the `onload` handler going to know to call `doFeedBack()` or `doFeedback();`? How are you telling it to call the JavaScript version? What's to stop it trying to still call the VBScript? None of this is addressed in the post.

Comment: @Lankymart, The vbscript function has been commented so it is no longer active. I showed both so as to let you see the effort that I have made. after conversion to javascripts with the 2 links, the key mistakes I made was in my loop (test(i) instead of test[i]) and I left out getStockDetail(SKU) in my conversion

Comment: @OlayinkaPopoola clarifying that in the question would be a start, how is anyone else supposed to know the other code was commented out? We can only critique what we can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify vbscript is not active as it is replaced with javascript.

The key mistakes I made was to use test(i) instead of test[i] in my loop. Also I left out
getStockDetail(SKU) function.

I used converter to resolve this by converting from vbscript to php and php to javascript.

I have resolved. found 2 converters online. I used the first to convert the code from vbscript to phh and the second from php to javascript. Links as shown below

https://richosoft2.co.uk/resources/jspack/asp2php.html

http://php2js.ru/en/php2js/class.html